# Create safe sqlite3 connection in PHP

Tags: php, security, sqlite

I want to create a user login/register but I think it is not really safe when I'm doing this:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mydatabase.sqlite3');
$users = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$userlist = Array();
foreach($users as $user)
{
 $userlist[] = $user['name'];
}
```

What's the best way to create a safe connection?

Comment: What do you think is not safe? This isn't a login/register system, looks to just be a list of users.

Comment: Your connection is ok. It sqlite itself that is a lightweight database system without any access control. If someone download your sqlite file, he can easily access to all your data. Make sure to set appropriate read/write permission for your db file. Also read [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally safe. But if you want to add parameters to the query, you can use prepared statements:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php